# If else statement in JavaScript keeps returning last else statement no matter user input

Tags: javascript

```js
     var age = prompt('How old are you?');
        if ('age' <= 5){
            alert("You are a baby!");
        }
        else if ('age' >= 5 && 'age' < 18){
            alert("You are a child!");
        }
        else if ('age' >= 18 && 'age' < 70){
            alert("You are an adult!");
        }
        else
            alert("You are a senior!");
```

So I am trying to make it change depending on user input for age. However, no matter the age I enter "You are a senior!" is the only alert that goes off.

Comment: Simply remove the quotes around **age** in the `if` conditions.

Comment: `'age'` is a string, since it is quoted. When you compare a string with a number in JavaScript, the number is converted to a string; and `'age'` comes after `'70'`.

Comment: Programming is all about small details.  The computer will always do exactly what you tell it to do, not what you thought you told it to do.  You must build in yourself the ability to notice small errors to be successful when programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove those inverted commas ' ' or quotes around `age` within If condition. By putting `'age'`, you are using it as a string, but it is a variable `age`.

```
  var age = prompt('How old are you?');
    if (age <= 5){
        alert("You are a baby!");
    }
    else if (age >= 5 && age < 18){
        alert("You are a child!");
    }
    else if (age >= 18 && age < 70){
        alert("You are an adult!");
    }
    else
        alert("You are a senior!");
```

Answer (score -1):

the problem is that when you make the comparison `if ('age' <= 5)` because of the quotes surrounding age is saying "if the string age is less than the number five" and that won't ever be true. Age is a variable that contains a number so as with all variables it shouldn't be surrounded by quotation marks.